# Stop SCV from building without cancelling

Tags: starcraft-2

In pro-level games, I often see Terran players pulling SCVs off half-completed buildings without cancelling the buildings (shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkDbfP6lMv0&t=1m56s)). How do you do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are referring to is the SCV Halt command (hot key T).  By issuing this command you can regain control of your scv and issue a movement command (moving it to safety) without canceling the building.  Another SCV can then be right clicked onto the building to finish it.